# Running into the problem of the UI not stretching out to the whole phone Despite being constrained and disabling the action bar

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I'm trying to create a ui and running into the problem of the UI not stretching out at the top. Even after I have constrained all the elements and have disabled the action bar.
[image: Desired UI created inside android studio]
[image: Android Manifest where I disabled the action bar and the UI inside the Virtual Device]
How do I remove that slightly gray bar at the top and have it be the color of the app itself ?

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge theme on both light and dark themes in android studio now it has two themes for light and dark mode based on user mode so use the above theme on both if you want to make status bar transparent you can use the following snippet

```
window.apply {
            clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
            addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                decorView.systemUiVisibility =
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR
            } else {
                decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            }
            statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context,android.R.color.transparent)
        }
```

window is the one you get from the activity

Comment: ah I see ! 
Just want to be sure though. should I apply this to the java files of each of the activities I want to be fullscreen ?
and thanks for the help !

Comment: yes you can keep this in your common util and call in all activities for transparent status bar

Comment: Noactionbar worked ! Thank you so much
I'll now have to look into how to make the status bar a specific colour since it still seems to be gray colour.
I guess it might be because I have made the app support the lowest sdk possible.